# Windows resize on primary monitor when I wake up the computer. Dual monitor setup

Tags: display, sleep-wake, mac-pro, displayport, dual-screen

**I have the following setup:**

- MacPro 2013 (trashcan)
- Primary / New Dell P2715Q monitor (2560x1440)
- Secondary / Acer H213H monitor (1080p)

**Problem:**

When my monitors go to sleep, I wake up the computer, login, and all of my applications have resized to fit within a 1080p size on the new Dell monitor. I then have to resize all of the windows to make them fit the Dell P2715Q monitor. Is there something I can do to eliminate that hassle?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So for anyone that might have this issue, in my case it was as simple as rebooting into safe mode.

I held down the shift key after the startup sound, released it when I saw the apple icon. After it successfully rebooted into safe mode I simply did a normal restart. I suppose this cleared out system caches and the windows stay put now after I wake up the displays.

*One weird issue when booting into safe mode that might help others as well. For some reason I had an issue with only seeing a cursor and a black screen. I assumed for some reason the login window just didn't display properly and I hit Escape and typed in my password as usual. I then noticed a spinning beachball and it logged in.